# I keep getting import errors for python

Tags: python, import

import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

errors:
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module names 'pymongo'

This happens on Windows and MAC OS :{

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to actually install `pymongo` (currently you just have mongo and python, but they do not know how to speak with each other).

Do:

```
pip install pymongo
```

Or read more at : https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/